# How to get the key from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am following the "[Quick Start](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html)" code of tsfresh python package (`pip install tsfresh`) as follows.

```
from tsfresh.examples.robot_execution_failures import download_robot_execution_failures, \
    load_robot_execution_failures
download_robot_execution_failures()
timeseries, y = load_robot_execution_failures()
from tsfresh import extract_features
extracted_features = extract_features(timeseries, column_id="id", column_sort="time")

import pandas as pd
extracted_features.to_csv("file.csv")
```

The `extracted_features` is a pandas dataframe. It has an `id` column when I write it to the `csv` file as shown in the image.

[image]

However, when I try to retrieve it as `extracted_features[["id"]]`, I get an error as `KeyError: "['id'] not in index"`. Is there a way to solve this issue.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Downvote. The header is wrong and the edit queue is full. The header must be: How to get the value of a chosen key in a dataframe? Asking to get the key in a df is totally vague, it could mean to get a key from the df.keys(), or to get the key(s) that leads to a chosen value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be that `id` is your index. Check the `extracted_features.index`

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to select a column you need to use the value of label that you want to select ("id"). If you are going to select more than one column then you need a list of labels.

You should use:

```
extracted_features["id"]
```

`"id"` is in the index but `["id"]` not in the index

---

if you want to select more than one column then if you can use a labels list:

```
extracted_features[["id","F_x__abs_e"]]
```

You can use to see the list of labels:

```
extracted_features.columns
```

You can use to see the list of index:

```
extracted_features.index
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. however, when I use `rextracted_features["id"]`, I get the error `KeyError: 'id'`. Is there a way to resolve this issue. Thank you :)

Comment: use: `extracted_features.columns` to see the list of columns.check that 'id' is present

Comment: It is not in `extracted_features.columns`. However, when I write the same dataframe to a csv file, I see that column in the csv file as shown in the image.  Do you know why this happens? thank you :)

Comment: what is the result of `extracted_features.columns` ? maybe you edit your ask and include it?. 'id' could be a value or element of the `index`

Answer (score 1):

I think "id" is name of your dataframe index. To get the index you need to do

```py
extracted_features.index
```